# How to handle a PBXCp error with EarlGrey?

Tags: earlgrey

[image]

I keep getting this error recently when I did a pod update, pod install and then executed my test cases using EarlGrey.
And when I try to resolve the path with terminal, I do not have anything in that path, nor do I have a EarlGrey-1.0.0 in my system.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer for the same seems to be a simple one.
Although had to struggle a lot to find and a lot of going back and forth with EarlGrey dev team.

First step is to fix the 'podfile'. 
Details below:

My podfile used to look like this while I encountered the problem.

[image]

And couldn't possibly figure out. Deleted 'Podfile.lock' and 'Pods' folder repeatedly and performed 'Pod update' and 'Pod install'. No luck.

Then I tried changing the path in "EarlGrey Copy Files" in Build Phases by browsing the 'framework' directly from my finder. Although that could solve my problem temporarily, it wasn't permanent. I checked my schemes to make sure if nothing got messed up there!

[image]
[image]
If all these are intact, then the problem is with podfile. As per the instructions mentioned here: https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/install-and-run.md#step-2-add-earlgrey-as-a-framework-dependency

or have a look at my fixed podfile below:
[image]
Add this line as mentioned in the post install hook. Then do a pod install and clean build, should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

although the above change may fix the problem, but after earlgrey gem 0.2 release, the integration process should be a lot smoother w/o any `post_install` or `require` in your Podfile.

for more info [here](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/pull/467)